# Protractor-cucumber : Continue remaining steps execution after assert failed in between instead of skipping the steps,

Tags: angular, automation, protractor, cucumber

I am using protractor-cucumber framework. But if any step is failed in the scenario, remaining steps are skipped. I want to just ignore that failure and want to continue executing remaining steps in the scenario.

Ex :
Scenario Outline: Test Scenario

Given User navigates to test site
 When User clicks on header link
 Then first then statement
 Then Second then statement

In this case if first then step assert fails then it will skip second step statement execution. But i want to ignore and continue with second step statement execution.

Please let me know how i can achieve this in protractor-cucumber. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using Chai-as-promised

expect(condition).to.eventually.equal(something).and.notify(next);